# Change the key in a dataframe dict

Tags: python, dataframe, key, try-catch, except

Hi all I have a DataFrame variables that I create from an xml file that is:

```
iva = df['p:FatturaElettronica']['FatturaElettronicaHeader']['CessionarioCommittente']['DatiAnagrafici']['IdFiscaleIVA']['IdCodice']

fis = df['p:FatturaElettronica']['FatturaElettronicaHeader']['CessionarioCommittente']['DatiAnagrafici']['CodiceFiscale']
```

Sometimes ['p:FatturaElettronica'] is ['FatturaElettronica']

Is there a method that I can use to change from one key to another without creating a  try except for any variable?

I've tried

```
try:
        df['p:FatturaElettronica']
        head = ['p:FatturaElettronica']
except KeyError:
        head= ['FatturaElettronica']
```

and change the variable like:

```
 iva = df[head]['FatturaElettronicaHeader']['CessionarioCommittente']['DatiAnagrafici']['IdFiscaleIVA']['IdCodice']
 fis = df[head]['FatturaElettronicaHeader']['CessionarioCommittente']['DatiAnagrafici']['CodiceFiscale']
```

but for the document with df['p:FatturaElettronica'] it raise a
KeyError at /files/xml/add
'FatturaElettronicaHeader'

that it seems like it does not change the head in p:FatturaElettronica

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?
thanks a lot for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I found a solution instead of using pandas I use xmltodict to read the xml file and I modify the try except:

```
try:
    df['p:FatturaElettronica']
    head = 'p:FatturaElettronica'
except KeyError:
    all_keys = list(df)
    head = all_keys[0]
```